# download image from URL string using UIImageView+AFNetworking.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have problem with download image from URL string. When I use this for download image and set in on imageView on view it works but now I have to set it on imageView on Cell.
I cannot put this on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method where I have access to imageView on cell.

```
__weak EditViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [weakSelf.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                               weakSelf.imageView.image = image;
                                               [self.tableView reloadData];

                                           } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                               [self prepareAndShowAlertView];
    }];
```

I'll be glad for any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you put this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this method was made for using it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only as it is very much optimised.

Comment: @sash you want to show image in uitableview cell imageview when table is load is it right?

Comment: no, when I click on imageView which is in my cell in UItableView it shows me alertView where I put url string, after that my method should try to download this image an put it into this imageView or show alertView again.

Comment: @sash : you can not download image from this code because this code show image on imageview. you want to download image then you must change your code if you are ready to change code then tell me i have send you code but you must be use latest AFNetworking use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to put your download to `cellForRow:AtIndexPath:` delegate method than you need to add `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;` to your controller and when image is downloaded

```
    ...success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

    weakSelf.imageView.image = image;
    self.image = image;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and in `cellForRow:AtIndexPath:` setup your image

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageView setImage:self.image];
    return cell;
}
```